# redirect .com domain to local server

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, iphone

Here is my particular setup:

-I have a local server with WiFi connectivity.

-It can act as an AP or Client, simultaneously.

-To connect from my iPhone in AP mode, I have to choose it's WiFi Network ( and disconnect the iPhone from my home internet connection) and type an iP 192.168.4.1

What I would like to do is:

-Keep my iphone connected to my home internet network.

-visit www.mydomain.com/local

-be redirected to my local server

Note that I don't want to mess with my router (current solution), and I want to access from any type of device.

Is this even possible ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Do you really need this?

You can [access a machine by its hostname](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16890/how-to-make-a-machine-accessible-from-the-lan-using-its-hostname).
[Here's a whole list of alternative techniques](https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/accessing-websites-on-a-local-network-lan-web-server)

#### If you want to do this, this is a way:

In short: You will need to setup a DNS server, which will tell your iphone where to find a certain domain (e.g. mydomain.com). You will tell your iPhone to use your own DNS server on your home network. When on your local network, your iphone will take you to your local server.

1. Setting up a DNS server
   We don't have much information on your server, but you'll have to install a DNS server. A commonly used server is [bind](https://www.isc.org/downloads/bind/). In this server's config, you need to create a zone and add DNS records for your server. Please note: I would advise against putting a .com in a local network. Just name your server "localdomain.localserver" or "localdomain.dev" or whatever you want, but prevent using TLDs which are already in use. This way you prevent trouble later on, when you can't visit the 'real' site for a domain you added in your local network.

   - [More detailled information on DNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_domain_name#How_does_a_DNS_request_work)
   - [More detailled information on DNS configuration](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/DNS-HOWTO-5.html)
   - [Bind setup tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04)
2. You need to tell your iPhone to use your own DNS server. You can easily find how to do this.

   - [Example tutorial](http://www.macinstruct.com/node/558)
3. Only redirecting a specific path.
   If you want to view mydomain.com on the internet (as usual), but you want mydomain.com/local to take you to your own domain, you can setup a redirect from mydomain.com/local to, for example, mydomain.dev (or whatever local name you have defined). This redirect will only work on your local network.

Comment: I agree, this sounds unnecessarily complicated.  What I really need is a way to connect to my server without having to switch to it's network on my iphone.  What would be the simplest way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried `http://computer-name/` or `computer-name.local` ? See the links at the top of my answer. We need more details about your (web)server (operating system, server software) for more detailled answers. 
Further reading: 
https://superuser.com/questions/139123/why-cant-i-access-my-own-web-server-from-my-local-network